# Generating source code with a gradle task based on existing classes with annotations on them

Tags: java, gradle, reflection, annotations, javapoet

**I am creating springboot applications, and most of the time I find myself writing boilerplate code for my models - repositories, services, controllers, builders... I do not want to do that.**

Based on my my experiences, previous works and researches I have a concept kind of developed in my mind. Basically the following:

1. I create an annotation

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface CodeGenSubject {
}
```

2. I create a processor

```java
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(CodeGenSubject.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for(Element e: roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CodeGenSubject.class)){
            // Observe fields and methods with reflection API
            // "Write" some code with JavaPoet
            // Place the generated code to the src/java folder
            // (with javax.annotation.processing.Filer)
        }
    }
}
```

3. I write my domain specific class

```java
@CodeGenSubject
@Entity
public class MyDomainSpecificEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String stuff;

    // getters and setters
}
```

4. And lasty, I create a gradle task (?)

```
task myCodeGeneratorTask(type: ???, group: "", desription: "") {
    // With this I am stuck
}
```

Ideally this template generator would be a separate module.

I have seen some example projects (mostly for android), and then I found the most promising:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder

Would be perfect, but... it uses maven, and the code is placed in a  totally impenetrable repository with a pom.xml file in the root project with a few thousand lines. Thanks : D

Right now I am working on an example multi-module gradle project with a springboot application. I have one entity (MyDomainSpecificEntity) and I am trying to make gradle generate some source code for me based on my annotation and processor.

Firstly, the biggest help would be some advice if I am conceptually wrong.

Secondly, if I am not, I would appreciate some help with that gradle script.

Lastly... the best would be a cleansed example project, If anyone ever played with this subject, and have some sort of public repo, that would be the most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have played with the concept and have an open source gradle plugin on github ([gradle-boilerplate-generator-plugin](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/gradle-boilerplate-generator-plugin)) that generates boilerplates.

It is a generic plugin to generate any type of boilerplates (the user can define their own using a simple **YAML** descripto, **FreeMarker** based templates and gradle closure configurations rather than java classes with annotations that you prefer). This plugin comes by default with a few demo boilerplates.

And, actually, one of these demo boilerplates includes (out-of-the-box) a task named `boilerplateWebServiceResource` to generate the typical Entity, DTO, Repo, Controller, Resource, etc. classes required for a typical web service resource.

[Its documentation](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/gradle-boilerplate-generator-plugin/blob/master/README.md) is very detailed on how to use it, configure it and extend it (create **custom boilerplates**). It may not be exactly what you are looking for; but you can send me suggestions, questions, fork it and modify it, or just maybe get ideas from it. Hope this helps.